# What pieces of information do you pass every time you do an authenticated action in your app?

Tags: api, security, authentication

So I will eventually have social logins but for now I'm local... username/password logins only.

When the user successfully validated I have set some local varabiles/preferences like:

```
usr_id: Integer 
loggedIn: ENUM('Y','N')
```

I pass these to the calls I make so that they won't be used by non-logged in entities but I feel this is hellishly insecure. What else can I pass to make sure that I know the right user is pulling the right information?

I was thinking of setting a "key" on login that would be in the database and locally in the app so that it would get passed as well.

Thanks

Comment: Tokens are pretty go to, this way you can pass the token with a request, authenticate against the token and not have to pass credentials or assume the user is authenticated.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell I'm only passing the username and pass once...then I'm setting the loggedIn and uid..but if the user is UID1 that is easy to brute force. Guess I'm going to issue a token as well and send with each request....SO I will put back the above information with the token as well..I'll just have to check the token for each call which is a bit more overhead.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't send any private/backend identifiers to the user. Instead have the token relate to the UID1 on the server. The less static information you use to authenticate (or identify) a user the less susceptible to a brute-force attack you become. In this scenario all the user is sending, once authenticated, is their username and token.

Comment: why bother with the username? That would be superfluous if you are sending the token...

Comment: It adds an extra level of complexity. That way someone can't just try to brute force a bunch of tokens.